# Parent-Child Processes

Tags: multithreading

What happens when the parent process of a child process  exits before the child ?

Answer (score 1):

Orphaned child processes all become the children of `init`, process 1.

Comment: i am not sure but doesn't that child process go to zombie state?

Comment: zombie is little different. The process is completed but yet has not return its value to parent process.

Comment: @Ankit Unripped children become zombies.